# Better approach on use of enum vs class with constants java

Tags: java, enums, log4j2

I'm still learning Java, and I have an issue where two, more experienced, engineers are asking me to follow two different approaches.
I'd like an opinion from more experienced java developers to choose one or the other approach and being able to defend that choice.

We're logging events using `Log4j2`. I've been asked to add categories to each log, as a prefix, as a way to tell where that log was created.

To avoid writing the category each time I was asked first to use a class, something like

```
public class LogCategory()
{
    public static final String CATEGORY_ONE   = "CategoryOne";
    public static final String CATEGORY_TWO   = "CategoryTwo";
    public static final String CATEGORY_THREE = "CategoryThree";
    ...
}
```

And it will be called using a `log4j2` logger like

```
private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyLogger");
logger.info("{}: This is a log", LogCategory.CATEGORY_ONE);
```

The`{}` works as the placeholder to prefix the string.

this method works fine. But then, another engineer asked me to replace that class for an enum, since this would be what the enum should be used for.
The enum was then declared like this

```
public enum LoggingCategory 
{
    CATEGORY_ONE("CategoryOne"),
    CATEGORY_TWO("CategoryTwo"),
    CATEGORY_THREE("CategoryThree"),
    ...

    private final String str;

    LoggingCategory(final String str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```

But due to the multiple signature that `log4j2` has for loggin methods, the `toString` method won't work unless explicitly called.
And it will be called using a `log4j2` logger like

```
private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyLogger");
logger.info("{}: This is a log", LoggingCategory.CATEGORY_ONE.toString());
```

Now I've been told that this explicit call of the `toString` method will affect performance, and it would be better to go back to the class.

So, is it true? The explicit call of the method affects performance?

Comment: Which signature of `Logger.info` gets called when you don't call the `toString()` on the enum? I would have expected `Logger.info(String, Object)` with and without the `toString()` method and this should result in the `toString()` method to be called on the `Object` anyways.

Comment: @cyberbrain Though that's likely almost always the case `Logger` is an interface and its [`info(String message, Object p0)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html#info-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)'s doc doesn't say anything about implicit `toString()` in an implementation.

Comment: @GeroldBroser--OnStrike: the Javadoc is underspecified, but for compatibility with the existent implementations `info(String, Object)` should stringify the message like [`ParameterizedMessage#getFormattedMessage()`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ParameterizedMessage.html) does. Hence a programmer can expect `toString()` to be called.

Comment: This is an example how sticking to some arbitrary rules dogmatically make a programmer’s life unnecessarily hard. What if you simply used `enum LoggingCategory { CategoryOne, CategoryTwo, CategoryThree}`? Your code would be shorter and you wouldn’t have to think about the difference between the name and the string representation of an enum constant. But well, somebody once said, these constants should have all-uppercase names and so we’re creating more code, just to obey that guy’s rule…

Comment: @Holger This  convention (not rule) absolutly makes sense, especially here at logging, to distinguish classes and domain-specific categories.

Comment: @GeroldBroser then, it would make more sense to keep the all-uppercase name through all logging layers and especially in text files, as that’s the place where these names would be hardest to distinguish. I was addressing the OP’s case where the logged string is *not* matching the name of the static field. If you prefer, e.g. `enum LoggingCategory { CATEGORY_ONE, CATEGORY_TWO, CATEGORY_THREE }`(again, without a contradicting `toString()` method), I wouldn’t object.

Comment: @Holger From this POV you're right. I, however, had a better approach (in my mind internally, so, agreed, not detectable for others) when writing this comment. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76452493/1744774) herein.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should avoid this kind of custom logging and instead use [appropriate factory method](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html)

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
```

This will add you appropriate identifier in your log message that will work as the category you want to introduce artificially.

Anyway - due to the good programming practices, however I find using enum here as some kind of overhead then saying that calling `toString` will affect performance is just a nonsense or, more politely saying, [premature optimization.](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

No matter which approach you will use - both are basically just fine and both are probably not really necessary in this particular scenario.

Comment: The logger is declared properly, here is just an example to clarify that `logger` is a Log4j2 Logger type.
Unfortunately, it won't work if I don't explicitly call `toString`

Comment: I'm not saying it's not but why are you then need to introduce artificial category and format it manually?

Comment: You still could use three different loggers with "MyLogger.CategoryOne", "MyLogger.CategoryTwo" and "MyLogger.CategoryThree" as names.

Answer (score 3):

I always like to go with `enum`s whenever possible because of their [type safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety#Java). That doesn't apply that much to library classes/methods the signature of which you can't change anyway (which basically is your case). But if it is in *your* own hands in *your* code...

I'd use `enum`'s anyway and declare them just as:

```
public enum LoggingCategory {

    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    ...
}
```

Because:

- that each of these represent a category is already stated in the `enum`'s name. Compare the usage `LoggingCategory.CATEGORY_ONE` to `LoggingCategory.ONE`.
- the `enum` doesn't need the members: variable, constructor, `toString()` since it supplies an implicit [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#toString()) which:

  > Returns the name of this enum constant, as contained in the declaration. This method may be overridden, though it typically isn't necessary or desirable. An enum class should override this method when a more "programmer-friendly" string form exists.
- All uppercase for categories' names is better to distinguish them from class names (in the logs).
- If you place your `enum`s in an external (to your business library) *commons* library they also can be used by others without the burden of importing and referencing (and loading into heap memory implicitily) full-featured business classes.

Answer (score 2):

The performance of the `toString()` is not an issue. If it has an impact, it is several orders of magnitude smaller than the performance of the logging call.

Using an enum is IMHO an overkill, since you don't really profit from the type safety it introduces. But if you want to use it, you should prefer:

```java
logger.info("{}: This is a log", LoggingCategory.CATEGORY_ONE);
```

over

```java
logger.info("{}: This is a log", LoggingCategory.CATEGORY_ONE.toString());
```

since the first line will only call `toString()` if `INFO` is enabled.

#### Note about the general approach

Adding the logging category as a string in the message is probably not the best idea, since you lose most filtering features. I would rather use:

1. Multiple loggers:

   ```java
   public class Loggers {
       public static final Logger CATEGORY_ONE = LogManager.getLogger("CategoryOne");
       public static final Logger CATEGORY_TWO = LogManager.getLogger("CategoryTwo");
       public static final Logger CATEGORY_THREE = LogManager.getLogger("CategoryThree");
       ...
   }
   ```

   Loggers are usually named after the class that uses them, but nothing prevents you from using you own names. They have excellent filtering features and are supported by **all Log4j API backends**. Logging backends are optimized to filter according to logger names.
2. Or I would use markers:

   ```
   public class Markers {
       public static final Marker CATEGORY_ONE = MarkerManager.getMarker("CategoryOne");
       public static final Marker CATEGORY_TWO = MarkerManager.getMarker("CategoryTwo");
       public static final Marker CATEGORY_THREE = MarkerManager.getMarker("CategoryThree");
       ...
   }
   ```

   that you can use as:

   ```java
   logger.info(Markers.CATEGORY_ONE, "This is a log");
   ```

   These are only supported by Logback and Log4j 2.x Core, but still offer adequate filtering features, although these come at a slight performance cost.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, TBH. First you write: "_You should however prefer: ... <enum examples> ..._". Then you write: "_Using an enum is IMHO an overkill_". :) +1 anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer to clarify that part. The `toString()` method should never be used explicitly, since it will be called by the backend if the log message is printed. There is even an [OpenRewrite option for that](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/logging/parameterizedlogging).

Comment: Thanks for that link. But doesn't the `rewrite.yml` there have an error? [YAML's Booleans are `true` or `false`](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#10212-boolean) as usual, not `null`.

Comment: I suppose that OpenRewrite's parser accepts both YAML booleans and nulls.

Comment: @Holger, oops, I honestly didn't notice the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

> *"So, is it true? The explicit call of the method affects performance?"*

The argument here is whether you're working in a professional environment or not.

If these are merely friends, or acquaintances, who are providing recommendations, then I would simply choose whichever approach offers the more scalable interface, than the other.
The mark in performance would be a millisecond measurement.

If it *is* a professional environment, then the latter recommendation is correct; that the *enum*'s conversion to a *String* will decrease performance.
The debate to provide some sort of latency threshold—e.g., 1 ms versus 5 ms—is not a topic, since the performance requirement is simply a standardization among the business.
If it can be displayed on a graph, then it's logical.

I prefer *enum* classes, they provide the ability to quickly enumerate a set of unique values, while also creating an easily scalable interface.

On the contrary, the first recommendation—of constant string values—can be a trivial design practice.

For example, in another situation, where you may be storing numerical values, in which their sequencing values are depended on, by calling objects.
The scalability is reduced significantly.

The *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* class uses this concept, to define *regular-expression* modes.
I've also seen it within the *Android API*.
And, if I'm not mistaken, I believe the *[Java AWT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/package-summary.html)* framework uses this pattern quite extensively.

Consider the following.

```java
static int VALUE_A = 1;
static int VALUE_B = 2;
static int VALUE_C = 3;
static int VALUE_D = 4;
```

If, in a future version of the program, I need to remove *VALUE_C*, it would require me to now edit the value of *VALUE_D*, along with any subsequent fields.
Which, consequently, would error the program at run-time, if not changed.

Since you are using *String* values, this isn't the case.  As, you know for a fact that it *will work*, since the scalability isn't really an issue.
This can be analogous to adding an *@SuppressWarnings* annotation above a statement.
You know there is a better design, and are telling the compiler to ignore it.

As a final note, I believe that the reason you are being told to choose the more archaic approach is because that is what, essentially, an *enum* object is converted into, at compile time.
An object with static fields.
Don't quote me on that.

Comment: The difference is probably in the 10s or 100s of nanos. Log4j 2 can print around a million of messages per second and the `toString()` call will certainly not be a bottleneck.

Comment: Re "_an_ enum _object is converted into, at compile time._" – There are no _objects_ (as we know them from a running JRE) at compile time. :) But you're basically right with: _A `*.class` file with `public static final` fields_.